# Polish diacritical marks in libcurl (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, libcurl

I just have a problem with a text that contains Polish diacritical marks (eg. ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż) obtained by libcurl from the server. I'm trying to display this text correctly in a Windows C++ console application.

I solved the similar problem with putting to the console screen something like that:

```
cout << "ąćęźół";
```

by switching codepage of my source file to: DOS Codepage 852 (Central Europe). Unfortunately it doesn't work out with text passing from libcurl. I think that it works only with the text written directly into the code. So could you tell my some helpful information? I have no idea how to resolve this issue.

Comment: When dealing with non-ASCII text, it's usually easier to resort to `std::wstring`. But even then VC++ doesn't have great support for Unciode in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've written temporary solution for my problem. It works fine, but I'm not contented of this way:

```
char* cpl(const char* input)
{
        size_t length = strlen(input);
        char* output = new char[length+1];

        /*  Order of the diacretics
            Ą ą Ć ć Ę ę
            Ł ł Ń ń Ó ó
            Ś ś Ź ź Ż ż
        */
        const size_t pld_in[] = {
            0xA1,0xB1,0xC6,0xE6,0xCA,0xEA,
            0xA3,0xB3,0xD1,0xF1,0xD3,0xF3,
            0xA6,0xB6,0xAC,0xBC,0xAF,0xBF,
        };
        const size_t pld_out[] = {
            0xA4,0xA5,0x8F,0x86,0xA8,0xA9,
            0x9D,0x88,0xE3,0xE4,0xE0,0xA2,
            0x97,0x98,0x8D,0xAB,0xBD,0xBE
        };

        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            bool modified = false;
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 18; j++)
            {
                if(*(input + i) == (*(pld_in + j)) + 0xFFFFFF00)
                {
                    *(output + i) = *(pld_out + j);
                    modified = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!modified)
                *(output + i) = *(input + i);
        }
        *(output + length) = 0x00;

        return output;
}
```

Could you propose better solution of this problem, without characters converting?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the web page returned by libcurl will use the character set of the web page. What's likely happening here is that it's not the character set used by your "codeset", which I presume the MS-Windows term for locale.

libcurl should let you look at the headers of the HTTP response that was received from the server. Look at the Content-Type: header, which will indicate which character set the returned text uses; then look up which codepage uses the same character set.

Comment: The website throws: "text/html; charset=iso-8859-2". So i tried to change console codepage using batch file:
chcp 28592
myapp.exe
And nothing has changed ;/

ID 28592 is an identificator of ISO-8859-2.

I have tried:
SetConsoleOutputCP(28592);
Still same bad signs.

Comment: Windows console APIs do not support Unicode very well if at all, even when you specify an output codepage. That is a well known limitation.  Output the downloaded data to something else, like a file, and you will see that the data is not the problem.